# .NET scheduled mass email open source solution

Tags: .net, email, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know of a solution (preferably open source, so that i can customize it to fit my needs), for **automatic sending of emails at scheduled intervals**?

If not, can anyone recommend a .NET technology that i could use to achieve this? I was thinking of using a Windows Service for this application, but the problem is that i have no experience developing Windows Services. I would like to build a WCF or ASP.NET deployable solution, but i'm not sure if the architecture of WCF or ASP.NET would allow me to do this without some ugly hacks.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MailSystem.NET](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com) contains everything you need including a template based mail merging system and a mail queuing service that supports scheduling.

It is free and open source.

Comment: Correction, this was exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 4):

It's quite easy to build one by yourself.

Theres a [mail client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) in the System.Net namespace and you have a scheduling component here: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

As for windows services, it's not really that hard. Visual Studio have a windows service project type that you can use to get everything that you need. Just put in some classes with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

"It's quite easy to build one by yourself."

Speaking from experience, I would not recommend this unless you have a year of free time. There are many elements that go into a full-featured mailing application and you'll want to at least start with some base code.